# How to remove duplicate entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as

```
col1                 col2
40647                1433,1433,1433,1454,1454,1433  
40648                1458,1458,1458,1458,67,67  
40649                866,866,866,866,866,866  
40650                798,798,798,798,798,798,798,798
```

i want to keep only the unique entries in col2 so, the ideal result would be

```
col1                 col2
40647                1433,1454  
40648                1458,67
40649                866 
40650                798
```

how do i achieve this?

Comment: presumably this works: `df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.split(',').str[0]`? can you explain what is actually stored is it a string, a list etc.

Comment: it is a list of strings

Comment: also, there can be multiple elements with duplicates.please see the edit

Comment: so you're saying it is actually stored like this: `['1433','1433','1433','1454','1454','1433'] `? if so please update your question and can you add code to reproduce your df

Comment: why don't you use `set` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) and let it handle deletion of duplicates itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple sample:

```
    col1      col2
0  40647    12, 25
1  40648    13, 25
2  40649     12,12
3  40650  12,12,12
```

You could try:

```
df.loc[:, 'col2'] = df.loc[:, 'col2'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: [i.strip() for i in x])
df.loc[:, 'col2'] = df.loc[:, 'col2'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x))]
```

and get

```
    col1      col2
0  40647  [12, 25]
1  40648  [13, 25]
2  40649      [12]
3  40650      [12]
```

Comment: this give me error
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.index.Int64Index'> with these indexers [col2] of <type 'str'>

Comment: hmm, this give me results like

40649        [8, ,, 6]  
40650     [9, 8, ,, 7]

Comment: lookslike it broke up the individual strings into characters and made a set out of that

Comment: looks like my col2 is a string

Comment: Depends really on how your column content is formatted exactly. I've added some string manipulation steps to get the data closer to a list without spaces.

Comment: My starting point would then be quite similar, let me know if you are running into any issues.